# How to plot a Clohessy Wiltshire trajectory on MATLAB?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, rendezvous

So I essentially want to plot the change in trajectory as I perform a maneuver using the clohessy wiltshire equations to chase a target. I have a for loop for 10,000s and I would like to calculate each value of r(t) as I run through the loop and then plot it. Anyone know how this would be done? I can post code if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
close all
n=0.00113;

phi_rr = @(t) [4-3*cos(n*t) 0 0; 6*(sin(n*t)-n*t) 1 0; 0 0 cos(n*t)];
phi_rv = @(t) [1/n*sin(n*t) 2/n*(1-cos(n*t)) 0; 2/n*(cos(n*t)-1) 1/n*(4*sin(n*t)-3*n*t) 0; 0 0 1/n*sin(n*t)];

r_0 = [100;0;0];
v_0 = [-1;-.115;0];

T=0:10:2000;

% plot red circle at origin
plot3(0,0,0,'ro')
hold on

% start loop
for t=T
    % display 50% progres
    if t==T(floor(end/2))
        disp('50 % done');
    end
    r=phi_rr(t)*r_0 + phi_rv(t)*v_0;
    plot3(r(1),r(2),r(3),'k.');
end
rotate3d
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
axis equal
grid on
hold off
```

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clohessy-Wiltshire_equations) and [this](http://www.ae.utexas.edu/courses/ase366k/cw_equations.pdf), x-axis points radially from center of gravity to the target, y-axis points into the targets direction of movement, and the z-axis is just perpendicular to the previous (right-handed system). So, with the initial values provided as an example above, the trajectory looks like this:

[image: example trajectory relative to the target]

The **view is relative to the target** (red circle), i.e. how the target sees the chaser move.

That means the chaser starts at 100 meters radially outwards of the target's position and with a velocity of -1 m/s radially inwards and -11.5 cm/s tangentially backwards relative to the target.

The chaser hits the target with non-zero velocity. So to make it more realistic, you'd have to do a multi-step simulation with subsequently decreasing velocity of the chaser.

Comment: Cheers! So I'm not quite sure whats going on with the "if t ===floor(T(end)/2)
disp('50% done') bit..can you explain what its for?

Comment: Good question! It is supposed to display when approx. 50 % of the calculation is done, since it can take a long time if T contains many numbers. But the way I coded it didn't make much sense... fixed!

Comment: so, to clarify your last point in your own answer (as I see you have a question related to it), you would do another burn that brings your relative velocity to zero at the target. The nature of these equations is such that for a given end condition, you can find the initial condition, so your v0 would be the values you need to be flying with to reach your target with 0 relative velocity, where as it seems you've picked an arbitrary value. Hope that helps with your other question too!